# How to start X application from SSH

Tags: linux

I've tried to search this topic in google, but without any signifant results.

I need to start some GUI app from terminal, but I don't care what this app is showing me. In addition, i need to start few instances of this application in diffrent sessions. It's connected with some GUI automated tests, so I know what I want and I'm looking for an answer :).

I think the proper steps should be:

1) Init new X window session 2) Get my new session id 3) export it to env variable (export DISPLAY:13.0) 4) run my app

but I'm stucked at first step. does anybody here had similar problem?

Comment: I think you can start an X application, you just need to connect with the `-X` or `-x` option. i.e `ssh -x`

Answer (score 1):

Xvfb is what I was looking for.

Exec a command in virtual x server:

```
 xvfb-run -a -w 10 command
```